# How to get password for Kibana (ECK) APM operator in kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack

ive followed this guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html, then apply this manifest:

```
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  version: 7.5.1
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 3
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  version: 7.5.1
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch
---
apiVersion: apm.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: ApmServer
metadata:
  name: apm-server
spec:
  version: 7.5.1
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: "elasticsearch"
  config:
    apm-server:
      rum.enabled: true
      ilm.enabled: true
      rum.event_rate.limit: 300
      rum.event_rate.lru_size: 1000
      rum.allow_origins: ['']
      rum.library_pattern: "node_modules|bower_components|~"
      rum.exclude_from_grouping: "^/webpack"
      rum.source_mapping.enabled: true
      rum.source_mapping.cache.expiration: 5m
      rum.source_mapping.index_pattern: "apm--sourcemap*"
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
```

Then with port-forward `kubectl port-forward pod/kibana-kb-5bb5bf69c9-5m5r5 5601` im trying to login to kibana but i cannot find any password for elastic search or kibana and look if the APM is working correctly... So, how do i get the password to access it? which secret is it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
kubectl get secret $ELASTICSEARCH_NAME-es-elastic-user -o=jsonpath='{.data.elastic}' | base64 --decode; echo
```

as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-kibana.html) did not work for you? Does that secret exist?

Comment: I get a string, but is that the user? the password? both?

Comment: it doesnt work with that string and user elastic, or kibana, or admin, or default

Comment: That's the password for the `elastic` superuser as it says in the linked doc. You should be able to log in with that password. Make sure you don't copy accidentally any line breaks or similar and it should work.

Comment: Well i was using the wrong version when installing everything, re installed with 1.3.0 instead of 1.0.0 and everything is working fine, thank you!

Comment: Just one note: in this case, the secret has its name because `elasticsearch`  is the name of the Elasticsearch object. The secret name has the form of `<elasticsearch-name>-es-elastic-user`. So, if in your Elasticsearch metadata you have `name: foobar`, the secret will be `foobar-es-elastic-user`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me : that does give the password for an 'elastic' user which works perfectly to connect to the ES API, but not on the Kibana web interface.